# matplotlib set_label_position no effect in 3d?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to move the position of the label of the axis in 3d view in matplotlib. I have tried `ax.xaxis.set_label_position` and `ax.xaxis.set_label_coords`. Both seem to have no effect. 
[image]

I'd like to move t/T_L away from the label ticks. How is it done?

Comment: I didn't test it in 3D Plots, but maybe you can use plt.text() instead of labels
http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Label padding in 3D plots does not work the same way as for 2D plots.

As shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26169316/588071), you *can* set the `labelpad` using `ax.xaxis._axinfo['label']['space_factor']`. Its not particularly pretty, but it works.

```
ax.xaxis._axinfo['label']['space_factor'] = 2.8
```

Comment: @Sleepyhead: it looks like in `matplotlib v1.5.0` mplot3d now resepcts the `{x,y}axis.labelpad rcParams` http://matplotlib.org/users/whats_new.html#configuration-rcparams