# shift the asix label along Z axis in mathplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, axis-labels, shift

I have a problem with shifting the label of z axis in z direction (along the axis) in 3d plot. I want to have the label of Z-axis at its end. I found that it should be possible for example by `ax.zaxis.set_label_coords(0,0,10)` but it does not work.

I am using the following code to generate the plot:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

%matplotlib notebook

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.xaxis.set_rotate_label(False)
ax.set_xlabel(r'$X$',fontsize=16,rotation=0)
ax.set_xlim3d(0, 9)
ax.yaxis.set_rotate_label(False)
ax.set_ylabel(r'$Y$',fontsize=16,rotation=0)
ax.set_ylim3d(0.35, 0.58)
ax.zaxis.set_rotate_label(False)
ax.set_zlabel(r'$Z$',fontsize=16,rotation=0, labelpad=5)
ax.zaxis.set_label_coords(0,0,10)
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 10)

ax.view_init(elev=30., azim=220)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I have no idea why `set_label_coords()` doesn't work in 3d plot, you can use `ax.text()` instead to draw the `z` label.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.xaxis.set_rotate_label(False)
ax.set_xlabel(r'$X$',fontsize=16,rotation=0)
ax.set_xlim3d(0, 9)

ax.yaxis.set_rotate_label(False)
ax.set_ylabel(r'$Y$',fontsize=16,rotation=0)
ax.set_ylim3d(0.35, 0.58)

ax.zaxis.set_rotate_label(False)
ax.set_zlabel(r'$Z$',fontsize=16,rotation=0, labelpad=5)
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 10)

ax.text(x=-1, y=0.58, z=11, s="z", color='red', size=8)

ax.view_init(elev=30., azim=220)

plt.show()
```

There are already some questions about `set_label_coords()` in 3d plot, but none gives a reason why it doesn't work.

- [matplotlib - How to adjust position of axis labels in 3D plots](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/How-to-adjust-position-of-axis-labels-in-3D-plots-td26445.html)
- [set_label_position no effect in 3d?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32973027/matplotlib-set-label-position-no-effect-in-3d)

[image]